# How to modify magento 2 submission form?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, shipping-address, customer-address

How can I add labels to the address fields.
Example:
**Field 1:**

**Field 2:**

**Field 3:**

[image]

Comment: you want to add new custom filed Right ? In shipping page?

Comment: Just add labels to the textfields of the address, and make them mandatory fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address fields already have label on checkout page but it sets hide in css by default.

So you just need to put below css in your theme's css file.

.field.street .field .label { display :block !important }

For the quick change of label text, you should use language csv file to convert text as below

"Street Address: Line 2","Line 2"

Here, i have shared screenshot that i have done for my client.

[image]

Thanks
Amit